# Mapping Ldap groups to role of the application in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, ldap

Need to configure Ldap to tomcat server for authentication and authorization purpose.
        I have declared the realm in serve.xml and i am able to bind the ldap server
        but i need to map the ldap groups to security roles but i am not able to do that
        i have made some configuration in web.xml below for role and group mapping but getting 403 error

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.test.TestServlet</servlet-class>

                <security-role-ref>
                    <role-name>admins</role-name>
                    <role-link>admins</role-link>
                </security-role-ref>

                <security-role-ref>
                    <role-name>users</role-name>
                    <role-link>users</role-link>
                </security-role-ref>

            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>

            <security-constraint>
                <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>Authentication</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
                    <http-method>GET</http-method>
                    <http-method>POST</http-method>
                </web-resource-collection>
                <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>admins</role-name>
                    <role-name>users</role-name>
                </auth-constraint>
                <user-data-constraint>
                    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
                </user-data-constraint>
            </security-constraint>

            <login-config>
                <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
            </login-config>

            <security-role>
                <role-name>admins</role-name>
            </security-role>

            <security-role>
                <role-name>users</role-name>
            </security-role>


        </web-app> 

    am missing any configuration for mapping 

    realm as below;
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"

                        connectionName="uid=admin,ou=system" connectionPassword="secret" authentication="simple"

                        connectionURL="ldap://localhost:10389" userSubtree="true"

                        userBase="ou=User,ou=ActiveMQ,ou=system" userSearch="(uid={0})"

                        roleBase="ou=Group,ou=ActiveMQ,ou=system" roleName="cn" roleSubtree="true"

                        roleSearch="(member={0})" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role Search pattern was wrong , i correct it as

```
roleSearch="(member=uid={1})
```

Now it works for me thanks